# I am building a reminder app in Flutter, and I want to trigger a function to update my database when the system time changes. How do I achieve it?

Tags: database, flutter, function, timer, sqflite

I have a todo list saved in database with the reminder date and time. So, I would like the app to update the database when the system time changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using [Cron](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) package.